# zf3 hydrate object having multiple subobjects

Tags: zend-framework3

I have a project with Zend Framework 3 and I need some help with hydrating objects with data from the database

I have an object User with properties name, phone ... and positions which is an array of position_id and position_name, which come from Position objects having properties id, name, work hours ....

Is it possible to have it hydrated by one query. Currently I am using query with Group_concat Expression and Explode strategy but I am not sure that this is the best approach, I checked the documentation regarding the Aggregate Hydrator, but I am not sure that it can be used... Here is simplified example:

```
Users table:
id  name  phone
1   Abc   1234-1234
2   Xyz   5678-5678

Positions table
id name   workhours.... 
1  PosA   ... ....
2  PosB   ... ....
3  PosC   ... ....


Users_positins table
id   user_id   position_id
1    1         1
2    1         3
3    2         1
4    2         2
5    2         3
```

My query is something like this:

```
Select 'users'['id', 'name']
Join 'users_positins'
Join 'positions' ['Group_concat (concat(id,';'name SEPARATOR ","']
```

And then i use ExplodeStrategy and Hydrator

```
 $this->hydrator->addStrategy('position_jd_revision_id', new ExplodeStrategy());
 $resultSet = new HydratingResultSet($this->hydrator, $this->userPrototype);
```

And in my model I have setter which converts string "id;name" to array [id]=>"name"
And I successfully receive my object witch looks like this:

```
user
  name->Abc
  phone->1234-1234
  positions->[1=>PosA, 3=>PosC]
user
  name->Xyz
  phone->5678-5678
   positions->[1=>PosA, 2=>PosB, 3PosC]
```

To clarify my question again - is it possible to get that result with one query and can positions be automatically hydrated Position objects array like this:

```
name->Abc
phone->1234-1234
positions->[Position{id->1, name->PosA}, Position{id->3, name->PosC}]
```

I checked Aggregate Hydrators but they look more useful when you have objects with not repeating subobjects.
What I imagine would be a good solutions is if I don't concatenate the positions properties so i will have multiples rows that hove the same user properties but different position properties, then somehow automatically detect which hydrated position objects should be inserted into which User objects...

Comment: Depends on what you want. Can you provide an example of your data? Will you fetch all data in once or will you just fetch identity keys and hydrator will fetch data with that identity from repository?

Comment: I need all data directly in the object and its sub objects directly hydrated at once if it is possible.What else do you need from my data, i think I have shown everything in my question?